# How to disable privileged container execution in Nextflow's Kubernetes executor?

Tags: kubernetes, nextflow

I'm running a Nextflow workflow using the Kubernetes executor in a shared cluster that cannot allow privileged containers for security reasons.

When I run my nextflow workflow I get the error that clearly indicates that it's attempting to run my job in privileged mode:

```
job-controller  Error creating: admission webhook "validation.gatekeeper.sh" denied the request: 
[psp-privileged-container] Privileged container is not allowed: nf-f48d29c6300b8f61af05447de0072d69, 
securityContext: {"privileged": true}
```

The Nextflow documentation suggests that I can set `privileged=false` in the `k8s.securityContext`. I've tried two different values to set privileged to `false` (one based on Nextflow docs, `privileged`, the other based on Kubernetes docs, `allowPrivilegeEscalation`). Both still yield the same error.

```
// Kubernetes config
process.executor = 'k8s'
k8s.namespace = 'mynamespace'
k8s.computeResourceType = 'Job'
k8s.securityContext.privileged = false                // nextflow doc format
k8s.securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation = false  // k8s doc format
```

I see the following related discussions that seem to suggest that this should work, but I'm having a hard time following these threads, or at least these threads seem to indicate that my `nextflow.config` is correct.

- [ERROR controller-runtime.controller - Privileged containers are not allowed spec.containers[1].securityContext.privileged #792][1]
- [feat: Support arbitrarily setting privileged: true for runner container #1383][2]

---

Update:

When nextflow submits my job, here's what the yaml looks like that Kubernetes receives. It looks like the job security context is empty, but that the pod template at `spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged = true`.

Noticing that I also tried setting `k8s.containers.securityContext.privileged = false` in `nextflow.config` but that was a wrong guess, I don't know how to index into the pod template settings.

It seems like I just need to figure out how to reference the pod template `securityContext` from `nextflow.config`.

```
$ kubectl get job nf-878eb722258681cf0031aeeabe2fb132 -n mynamespace -o yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  annotations:
    batch.kubernetes.io/job-tracking: ""
  creationTimestamp: "2023-09-12T17:16:58Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    nextflow.io/app: nextflow
    nextflow.io/processName: helloWorld1
    nextflow.io/runName: focused_pesquet
    nextflow.io/sessionId: uuid-2a634652-ba40-4905-a9ca-ad0b948df4f0
    nextflow.io/taskName: helloWorld1
  name: nf-878eb722258681cf0031aeeabe2fb132
  namespace: mynamespace
  resourceVersion: "6387865826"
  uid: 6a4ce939-cc01-4298-9d94-84219d750e84
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  completionMode: NonIndexed
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      controller-uid: 6a4ce939-cc01-4298-9d94-84219d750e84
  suspend: false
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        controller-uid: 6a4ce939-cc01-4298-9d94-84219d750e84
        job-name: nf-878eb722258681cf0031aeeabe2fb132
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /usr/bin/fusion
        - bash
        - /fusion/s3/mybucket/nextflow/87/8eb722258681cf0031aeeabe2fb132/.command.run
        env:
        - name: FUSION_WORK
          value: /fusion/s3/mybucket/nextflow/87/8eb722258681cf0031aeeabe2fb132
        - name: AWS_S3_ENDPOINT
          value: custom.ceph.endpoint
        - name: FUSION_TAGS
          value: '[.command.*|.exitcode|.fusion.*](nextflow.io/metadata=true),[*](nextflow.io/temporary=true)'
        image: wave.seqera.io/wt/8602f8b269fe/library/ubuntu:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nf-878eb722258681cf0031aeeabe2fb132
        resources:
          limits:
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 1Gi
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Never
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: default
      serviceAccountName: default
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 604800
status:
  ready: 0
  startTime: "2023-09-12T17:16:58Z"
  uncountedTerminatedPods: {}
``


  [1]: https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller/issues/792
  [2]: https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller/pull/1383
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Nextflow's Kubernetes executor](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html#k8s-executor), you have the ability to control the security context of the pods that are created.

You need to correctly specify the security context in such a way that it applies to the correct level within your Kubernetes job specification. It appears that Nextflow is *not* applying the `securityContext` to the individual containers within the pods based on the settings in your `nextflow.config`.

You can try and utilize the [`pod` directive](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-pod) within your Nextflow process definitions to specify custom pod settings. You would specify the security context within the pod directive using Groovy syntax to create a YAML snippet that represents the correct Kubernetes configuration.

```
process {
    ...
    
    pod = [
        'spec': [
            'containers': [[
                'name': 'main',
                'securityContext': [
                    'privileged': false
                ]
            ]]
        ]
    ]
}
```

You can see the `pod` directive, used to define a custom pod configuration, using a map of configurations (and not a YAML multi-line string) to represent the YAML configuration for the Kubernetes pod. We specify a `securityContext` at the pod level with `runAsUser: 1000` to dictate the user ID that the process will run as (replace `1000` with an appropriate user ID for your environment).

Within the `containers` list, we specify a container named "main" and set `privileged: false` in its `securityContext` to disable privileged mode for that container.

That configuration should override the defaults applied by Nextflow and allow your job to run without privileged mode.

Comment: This looks like it's on target, thanks! I just have to figure out the right syntax. This gives an error `Cannot cas object <YAML-STRING> with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'`. I'm trying to figure out what it was expecting for `pod`. I'll probably have to start diving through the code unless someone here knows, the docs don't go this deep.

Comment: @DavidParks I have edited the answer to propose an alternative syntax, which might be compatible with what is expected.

Comment: `Unknown pod options: [spec:[containers:[[name:main, securityContext:[privileged:false]]]]]` I'm starting a new question on how to properly structure `pod` `securityContext`. I think you've nailed the answer I was primarily after here, and the syntax question should be split out, I can update this later. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77092888/how-to-correctly-format-the-pod-securitycontext-directive-in-a-nextflow-workfl

Comment: @DavidParks Good point. I have edited the answer to propose a fix in the map structure, but if that does notwork, your new question should do the job;

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that not using privileges can lead to permissions errors (ie. file permissions errors, the .sh file on your error message maybe).
Add one of the following snippets to your Nextflow configuration:

```
// 1-cloud executors
    
process.containerOptions = "--user 0:0"

// 2-Kubernetes

k8s.securityContext = [
"runAsUser": 0,
"runAsGroup": 0
        ]
```

Further info [K8s official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)

Comment: I've configured nextflow to run on an S3 bucket filesystem so I don't expect any file permissions issues running in non privileged mode. I'm not trying to set the user in the container (which is what you appear to be doing here), I'm trying to disable the privileged model execution which isn't allowed in my environment. Also `k8s.securityContext.privileged` is not having any effect, likely due to changing the security context of the job and not the pod template.