# How to correctly format the `pod.securityContext` directive in a nextflow workflow?

Tags: nextflow

I'm trying to configure the `pod` directive in a Nextflow process [(docs here)](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-pod). I'm attempting to follow the solution [provided in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77062492/how-to-disable-privileged-container-execution-in-nextflows-kubernetes-executor/77091542#77091542), allowing me to override `privileged` container execution at the pod level.

*Notable update:* I'm using the Fusion executor and Claude.ai thinks that the Fusion executor seems to be building the pod spec and thus ignoring any Nextflow configuration I set.

This is the syntax proposed in that answer (which I believe is a correct answer, but the syntax is not right):

```
process {
    ...
    
    pod = '''
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
      containers:
      - name: main
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
    '''
}
```

When I try that I get an error `Cannot cas object <YAML-STRING> with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'`.

I've tried every other way I can think of to format the part I care about, none of these worked (I tried quite a few more than the two examples listed).

```
    pod = [
      securityContext: {
        privileged = false
      }
    ]
```

```
     pod = [
       {
         'containers': [{
           'securityContext': {
             'privileged': false,
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
```

```
    pod = [
        'spec': [
            'containers': [
                [
                    'name': 'main',
                    'securityContext': [
                        'privileged': false
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

The Nextflow documentation lists 3 different ways you could use the `pod` directory for the simplest case of an environment variable, and no example of how a more complex `securityContext` might be formatted other than just `securityContext: <V>`, I don't know how to format `<V>`, nor where exactly the lists are supposed to be and why.

---

Here's a **minimum reproducible** test case using a format suggested in an answer to this question:

```
params.xyz = 'notset'

workflow {
    data = helloWorld1(params.xyz)
}

process helloWorld1 {
    container 'ubuntu:latest'

    // Define the resource requirements
    cpus 1
    memory '1 GB'
    disk '1 GB'

    input:
    val xyz

    output:
    file 'output.txt'

    pod = '''
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: main
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          privileged: false
    '''

    """
    echo "Running Hello World Container 1! UUID: ${xyz}"
    """
}
```

Error:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.08.0-edge
Launching `/workflows/demo_workflow.nf` [serene_shirley] DSL2 - revision: 3dddc9f196
Downloading plugin nf-amazon@2.1.1
Downloading plugin nf-wave@0.11.1
[7f/b043d7] process > helloWorld1 [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'helloWorld1'

Caused by:
  Cannot cast object '
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: main
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          privileged: false
    ' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'

Command executed:

  echo "Running Hello World Container 1! UUID: 1970-01-01-e-demo"

Command exit status:
  -

Command output:
  (empty)

Work dir:
  s3://braingeneersdev/nextflow/7f/b043d75c3e95131b0134e79c444a8a

Tip: when you have fixed the problem you can continue the execution adding the option `-resume` to the run command line

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
```

Addition:

The Job yaml that gets submitted by nextflow is this (looking at `spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged=true`:

```
$ kubectl get job nf-712e8588dc4c74af67c1072222600662 -o yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  annotations:
    batch.kubernetes.io/job-tracking: ""
  creationTimestamp: "2023-10-05T19:57:31Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    nextflow.io/app: nextflow
    nextflow.io/processName: helloWorld1
    nextflow.io/runName: cranky_poincare
    nextflow.io/sessionId: uuid-dc43071e-8de1-49cb-bbf1-04cd69fc9e01
    nextflow.io/taskName: helloWorld1
  name: nf-712e8588dc4c74af67c1072222600662
  namespace: mynamespace
  resourceVersion: "6497397913"
  uid: 9154ce7e-c032-42ec-b916-ebd503a102f7
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  completionMode: NonIndexed
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      controller-uid: 9154ce7e-c032-42ec-b916-ebd503a102f7
  suspend: false
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        controller-uid: 9154ce7e-c032-42ec-b916-ebd503a102f7
        job-name: nf-712e8588dc4c74af67c1072222600662
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /usr/bin/fusion
        - bash
        - /fusion/s3/mybucket/nextflow/71/2e8588dc4c74af67c1072222600662/.command.run
        env:
        - name: FUSION_WORK
          value: /fusion/s3/mybucket/nextflow/71/2e8588dc4c74af67c1072222600662
        - name: AWS_S3_ENDPOINT
          value: s3.our-endpoint
        - name: FUSION_TAGS
          value: '[.command.*|.exitcode|.fusion.*](nextflow.io/metadata=true),[*](nextflow.io/temporary=true)'
        image: wave.seqera.io/wt/d81a7110bdba/library/ubuntu:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nf-712e8588dc4c74af67c1072222600662
        resources:
          limits:
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
            memory: 1Gi
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Never
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: default
      serviceAccountName: default
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 86400
status:
  ready: 0
  startTime: "2023-10-05T19:57:31Z"
  uncountedTerminatedPods: {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer to this in the Nextflow Slack channel from Jordi Deu-Pons, he stated:

> We are working on a k8s fuse device plugin to allow to use Fusion without privileged (it's on testing phase; so should be available soon). Notice that we have the #fusion-fs channel for this kind of questions.

The `privilege` mode is being set by the Fusion filesystem and couldn't be overridden by the normal settings in the k8s executor.

An update on that thread:

> Now it is possible to use Fusion and K8s without privileged flag. Use latest Nextflow and set `fusion.privileged = false`. This requires [this](https://github.com/nextflow-io/k8s-fuse-plugin) FUSE device plugin on your k8s.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for defining a pod with a `securityContext` in Nextflow is to use triple-single-quotes (`'''`) for preserving the multi-line YAML block.

```
process helloWorld1 {
   container 'ubuntu:latest'

   // Define the resource requirements
   cpus 1
   memory '1 GB'
   disk '1 GB'

   input:
   val xyz

   output:
   file 'output.txt'

   // Define the pod configuration as a Groovy map
   pod:
   '''
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: main
       securityContext:
         runAsUser: 0
         privileged: false
   '''

   script:
   '''
   echo "Running Hello World Container 1! UUID: ${xyz}"
   '''
}
```

Make sure you use triple-single-quotes (`'''`) for the pod block, and it should work without errors.

Comment: That's the first format we tried, which failed. That generates an error: `Cannot cast object <yaml string shown in answer> with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'`. That's why we started playing with lists.

Comment: I added a minimum reproducible test case to the question, along with the full error that was generated using this format.

Comment: You're trying to define a Kubernetes Pod configuration within a Nextflow process using YAML, and you're encountering an error related to the formatting of the pod directive. You need to define the pod directive as a Groovy map instead of a YAML string. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions and I get `Invalid process definition -- Unknown keyword 'pod'` on the `pod: """` version and the same error as before, `Cannot cast object <yaml string shown in answer> with class 'java.lang.String' to class`, when trying the second format with the string in a list.

Comment: Are you using (`'''`) or (`"""`) because there's a difference. In Groovy, using triple-single-quotes (`'''`) allows you to define multi-line strings with line breaks preserved as-is, including any indentation. This is important when defining YAML or other multi-line configurations, as it ensures that the formatting and indentation of the YAML block are preserved correctly.

Comment: I've tried it with both `'''` and `"""` for 3 forms: `pod: '''`, `pod = '''` and `pod = [ '''`. All six approaches give me either the process definition or cast error.

Comment: @DavidParks Have you tried `pod: ''' ... '''` as seen in my latest answer?

Comment: When I use `pod: ''' ... '''` whether I put the first `'''` on the same line with `pod:` or the next line, both forms give me `Script compilation error - cause: Invalid process definition -- Unknown keyword 'pod' @ line 29, column 10.` then it points at the first character of the triple single quotes on the next line.

Answer (score -2):

The `pod.securityContext` directive is a part of the process configuration, and it allows you to set security-related attributes for the pods.

Here's how you can correctly format the `pod.securityContext` directive in a Nextflow workflow:

```
    container 'your-docker-image' // Replace with your Docker image

    // Other process configuration settings...

    pod {
        memory '1Gi' // Set the memory limit for the pod
        cpu '0.5'    // Set the CPU limit for the pod
        // Add additional security context settings if needed
        securityContext {
            runAsUser 1000 // Set the user ID to run the container
            runAsGroup 1000 // Set the group ID to run the container
            fsGroup 1000 // Set the group ID for file system access
        }
    }

    script:
    """
    # Your process script commands here
    """
}
```

In the above code:

`container` specifies the Docker image that this process will run in.
Inside the `pod` block, you can specify the resource requests and limits for the pod using `memory` and `cpu`.
The `securityContext` block allows you to configure security-related settings for the pod.
In the `securityContext`, you can set the `runAsUser`, `runAsGroup`, and `fsGroup` to specify the user and group `IDs` under which the `container` should run.
Replace `'your-docker-image'` with the Docker image you want to use and adjust the security settings, resource limits, and any other process-specific configurations as needed.

Make sure to adapt this configuration to your specific requirements and Docker image. Keep in mind that the exact options available may vary depending on your Kubernetes cluster's configuration and the specific version of Nextflow you are using.